# Как убрать повторный рендер элемента? React

Tags: reactjs

Есть вот такой маленький пример компонента `App`:

```
import React from 'react';

const Child = () => <div>I'm Child</div>
const MChild = React.memo(Child);
const Parent = (props) => <div>{props.children}</div>
const MParent = React.memo(Parent)

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>setCount(count+1)}>{count}</button>
      <MParent>
        <MChild />
      </MParent>
    </div>
  )
};

export default App;
```

Если нажать на кнопку и использовать `react devtools`, то можно увидеть, что компонент `MParent` повторно рендерится по причине измененного `children`. Вопрос можно ли как-то избавиться от повторного рендеринга `MParent`?

Comment: Не совсем понятно зачем тут React.memo... Но я воспроизвел твой пример у себя - у меня рендер был всего один.

Comment: `MParent` в принципе тут не нужен, а вот чтобы не перерендеривался `Child` нужен уже `React.memo`

Comment: Оба компонента определяются только при обращении к модулю и более не меняются. Т.е. ссылка на функцию будет неизменна.

Answer (score 0):

Я проверил пример ТСа - у меня получается всего один рендер...

```js
const Child = () => <div>I'm Child</div>
const MChild = React.memo(Child);
const Parent = (props) => {
    console.log('MParent')
    return <div>{props.children}</div>
}
const MParent = React.memo(Parent)

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>setCount(count+1)}>{count}</button>
      <MParent>
        <MChild />
      </MParent>
    </div>
  )
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: При клике на кнопку, повторно рендерится `MParent`, хотя он не изменяется никак. Но я уже вроде разобрался. Он рендерится т.к. рендерится `App`, который в свою очередь перерендеривается из-за измененного состояния `count`. И решение заключается в том, чтобы создать новый компонент `Counter` например и туда перенести это состояние и кнопку. Тогда будет рендерится только `Counter`.

Comment: Все верно. Меняется стейт - это вызывает рендер компонента.

Comment: @Bonifacy, при такой компоновке компонентов React.memo() не изменит общую картину, поскольку они и так инициализируются только при обращении к модулю и более не меняются...

Comment: Не совсем понял вас. Если убрать `MChild` то и `Child` будет перерендериваться вместе с `MParent`. При такой компоновке не получится только `MParent` заставить не рендериться снова, а `Child` можно при помощи `React.memo`

Comment: Тут не стоит путать рендер компонента и собственно его создание. Рендер будет вызываться только в двух случаях - изменение стейта или пропсов. И применение меморизации на это никак не влияет... А вот на определение самой функции уже может оказать влияние меморизация этой функции. Но. В твоем варианте функции определены в модуле, а не в каком-то другом компоненте. Как только кто-то подключит модуль для получения компонента App, а это будет наверное всего один раз. Сразу же определятся Parent и Child. Более они переопределяться и так не будут. Т.о. ссылка на функции меняться не будет.

Comment: И смысла меморизовать их нет.